# Have NO idea why this JQuery animate is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Okay so basically I have 3 divs, called first, nextscreen, and finalscreen. I created some jquery that allows the divs to slide in and out of view, when pressing next or back. Animating from first to nextscreen when pressing Next >>> and <<< Back works, UNTIL I press Next >>> to animate from nextscreen to finalscreen. When I go <<< Back from finalscreen to nextscreen, and then try go <<< Back from nextscreen to first, NEXTSCREEN SIMPLY DOES NOT MOVE. However if I try make it slide out to the left it does work, but I need it to slide out to the right, or it just looks silly. This is my html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="first" style="position: relative; right: 0px">
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tableName">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tableName" name="tableName" placeholder="Name your list..." />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Description">Description</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="Description" name="Description" placeholder="Provide a brief description of this list..." rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="next">Next >>></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="nextscreen" style="right: -2000px; top: -220px; position: relative">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="addField">Add Field</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addField" placeholder="Field Name..." />
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add">Add Field >>></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fieldList">Field List</label>
                <select multiple class="form-control" id="fieldList" style="height: 200px">
                    <option>Name*</option>
                    <option>Cell*</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <p>* Compulsory fields</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="back"><<< Back</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="final">Next >>></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="remove"><<< Remove Field</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="SelectedOptions" id="Name" value="Name" />
            <input type="hidden" name="SelectedOptions" id="Cell" value="Cell" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="finalscreen" style="right: -4000px; top: 0px; position: relative">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="createtable">Create Table</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="finalback"><<< Back</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my JQuery:

```
$("#next").click(function () {
    $("#first").animate({ left: '-2000px' });
    $("#nextscreen").animate({ right: '0px' });
    $("#finalscreen").animate({ right: '-2000px' });
});

$("#final").click(function () {
    $("#first").animate({ left: '-4000px' });
    $("#nextscreen").animate({ left: '-2000px' });
    $("#finalscreen").animate({ right: '0px' });
});

$("#back").click(function () {
    $("#first").animate({ left: '0px' });
    $("#nextscreen").animate({ right: '-2000px' })
    $("#finalscreen").animate({ right: '-4000px' });
});

$("#finalback").click(function () {
    $("#first").animate({ left: '-2000px' });
    $("#nextscreen").animate({ left: '0px' });
    $("#finalscreen").animate({ right: '-2000px' });
});
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yjZBe/

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Nope, have checked that. Added a JSfiddle now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be way easier and efficient to place those elements in a container and animate only that one instead of each element.

Comment: Okay, but I need all 3 to move not just one.

Comment: Yeah but they all move the same way, so you keep all of them still and animate the container, so it'll look like you're animating each element

Comment: Ok I see. I'm busy trying that now, but it doesn't seem to be working, i.e. nothing moves at all now, http://jsfiddle.net/yjZBe/6/

Comment: It's because you're animating the "left" attribute, so you need to set #containment {
    position: absolute;
} in your css